# When is PropertyChangedEventManager created and when is it attached?

Tags: .net, wpf, memory-leaks, inotifypropertychanged

To make a very long story short…  This is in a large WPF project

I have a class “Patient” that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  When I dispose this class I am checking that the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` is null and if not run it to a `ListenerDetector` class that logs the listeners so we can track them down and clean the leaks.  Patient does have some properties that are bound to WPF elements as well as other objects the use its `PropertyChanged` to monitor changes.

After disposing everything else, my log result is as follows:

> Log: Patient still has the following listener(s) attached: 
>     - `System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager`

Question: 
 When is the `PropertyChangedEventManager` created?

- When Patient is created
- When WPF binds to Patient property
- Some other point.

If `Patient.PropertyChangedEventHandler` is set to `null` and therefore disconnected from the `PropertyChangedEventManager` is there any way to recreate the Manager and have it listen to the `Patient.PropertyChangedEventHandler` again?  Please don’t ask why this would happen, that is a point of tension here :-(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `PropertyChangedEventManager` is created by WPF in order to support binding to any class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  It'll be created and used as soon as you bind to *any* class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

That being said, its an implementation of the [WeakEventManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.weakeventmanager.aspx) pattern.  While it's still showing a listener attached, realize that this listener is attached using the [Weak Event Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx).  This will go away as soon as a full garbage collection occurs, as it's using weak references to hold the subscription.  As such, this particular subscription shouldn't be the cause of a (long term) memory leak.